# Stopping Purchase IPad App from being Bulk Deployed

Tags: iphone, ipad, deployment, app-store

We are creating an enterprise IPad app that we will be selling of the App Store for a price (e.g. $500). Is there anyway to stop a customer from purchasing the App once and than deploying it on to more devices? Is there a way to identify the device-id of the ipad/iphone that made the purchase and than cross-check this on our systems?

If there is no way of getting around it I was thinking that the app could be downloaded for free and we would manage the registration through our system. But I think Apple might say this is a no-go.

Just want advice on this issue because Im sure im not the first person to come across this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your app will priced so high probably an Apple reviewer will call you asking about that price. He will tell you to distribute it in other ways (ad-hoc, enterprise) if you don't plan to sell several hundred units.

My thought is to start distributing it directly in other ways.

And there's no way to prevent installation on more than one device: any user can and should install it on every device he owns.

Comment: You can only distribute Ad-Hoc to 100 devices.

Comment: Ad-Hoc distribution would be great but we are going to need to be able to distribute to well over 100 devices. Is there anyway that Apple allow you to ad-hoc distribute to over 100 devices?

Comment: @IPadHackAndSlash join the enterprise developer program.

Comment: But with the enterprise developer program I have read that your app can only be published to in-house devices. Apple wouldnt allow me to publish to outside clients would they?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your app does, it might be considered a Software as a Service-type offering, a la Netflix. Then you could theoretically manage subscriptions outside of the app and do your own installation limiting.

At least, that's what a previous [email](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/02/21/steve-jobs-email-suggests-in-app-subscriptions-dont-apply-to-software-as-a-service/) from Steve Jobs would imply.

They've let in apps that limited the number of users for other reasons - for instance, Flipboard turned off new user registration and just included a waiting list signup screen.

You'd need to provide login info with your app submission for the App Reviewer to use.